# p4 paths import are not coming to workspace

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-stream

If I type

```
p4 stream -o -v //path/to/My/stream
```

I could see the following items in  `Paths`

```
Paths:
        share ...
        import+ Foo/proto/... //Depo1Path/api/api_main/...
        import+ Bar/proto/... //Depo2Path/SomeProjectname/proto/...
```

When I create a workspace with [Helix Visual Client (P4V)](https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-visual-client-p4v) of `//path/to/My/stream` both `Foo/proto/` and `Bar/proto/` are coming properly. But when I create workspace with p4 command from shell script, `Foo/proto/` and `Bar/proto/` are not coming to the workspace.

My script is given below

```
export P4CLIENT=$workspaceName
mkdir -p ${checkoutDir}
cd ${checkoutDir}
p4 client -i <<HERE
Client:     ${P4CLIENT}
Owner:      ${P4USER}
Root:       ${checkoutDir}
Options:    noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir
View:       
            ${depotPath}    //${P4CLIENT}/...
HERE
p4 sync -f
```

Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Stream client you must specify the Stream field and omit the View field.

Assuming "depotPath" is your stream:

```
p4 client -i <<HERE
Client:     ${P4CLIENT}
Owner:      ${P4USER}
Root:       ${checkoutDir}
Options:    noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir
Stream:     ${depotPath}
HERE
```

Comment: This worked, I should use `${depotPath}`  as `//path/to/My/stream` instead of
`//path/to/My/stream/...`